# visual studio code node.js debugger fails to attach on standard launch

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I tried to use the simple node.js example visualstudio code provides, but unfortunately when node is being started from visual studio code (on OS X) the node gets started with some arbitrary debug-brk, but debugger attachment fails.

When I run the node app manually with --debug-brk = 5858 and then use the attach I can debug my app. Anyone faced the same problem?

P.S I got mono installed from the mono project page .pkg

Here is my launch.js:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
// List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.  
// ONLY "node" and "mono" are supported, change "type" to switch.
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch app",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "./bin/www",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": { }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Hmm while tracing what is code actually doing it is kinda depending on how long it takes to start terminal and processes and uses simple lsof and grep to look for running node ... when you incur a slight delay the debugger will attach. So overall I think we can call it a bug.

Comment: What is your Node version? You can find it out by typing in Terminal `node -v`. It is noted somewhere in fine print that v0.12.0 and higher is recommended.

Comment: This is the only report of this issue so far. I've created a bug on our side to increase the number of connection attempts. A fix will appear in our next update.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue on OS X with VSCode 0.5.0, node 0.12.7, and Mono 4.0.2. Launching debugger tried to do --debug-brk=55324 or a similar number before it Killed: 9. If I manually run the debugger at 5858, I can attach and debug.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same issue... Code couldn't find Node.

Change this line to point to your executable, for example:

"runtimeExecutable": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",

Enjoy!

Comment: when it is remained empty it should be the one on `PATH`, but null didn't work me either .Absolute path did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the cluster thing. Try to turn off cluster in ./bin/www, and you will be able to debug it.